# Django App Deployment - 504 Timeout - No module named 'encodings' (Ubuntu 18.04, Django 2.2.1, Python 3.7, Apache 2.4.29, mod-WSGI 4.6.7)

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

Problem: Followed standard setup for Django web app. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, Django 2.2.1, Python 3.7, Apache 2.4.29, mod-WSGI 4.6.7, and virtualenv to create a virtualenv. When I attempt to access my site (either IP or FQDN) I get a 504 Gateway Timeout Error

I check the Apache2 logs and am getting the following error at 1-second intervals:

Current thread 0x00007f52f8874bc0 (most recent call first):
[Mon Sep 23 02:49:26.540404 2019] [core:notice] [pid 9896:tid 139994333662144] AH00051: child pid 10305 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

python manage.py runserver works fine and I can access through either IP or FQDN via browser from other devices. There are no problems with the database or other issues (although when using FQDN instead of IP # I am getting 404 error on CSS/JS, although rest loads - but this is potentially a separate issue)

I have tried:
* Resetting up virtualenv
* Resetting up Apache2
* Different apache .conf arrangements
* I watched @Graham Dumpleton's excellent video from PyCon Au 2010 "Getting Started with Apache/mod_wsgi." and tried to implement some of his insights

Apache2 Conf

```
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
...
...
    Alias /static /project/static
    <Directory /project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /project/media
        <Directory /project/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

    <Directory /project/main>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/project python-home=/project/venv
    WSGIScriptAlias / /project/main/wsgi.py process-group=django_app
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2 Error File

```
Current thread 0x00007f52f8874bc0 (most recent call first):
[Mon Sep 23 02:49:26.540404 2019] [core:notice] [pid 9896:tid 139994333662144] AH00051: child pid 10305 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

UFW Status

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: This is usually a variation of https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#multiple-python-versions Your mod_wsgi is compiled for a different Python installation than your virtual environment is created from, or, mod_wsgi isn't finding the correct Python shared library for the Python installation because you are trying to use a custom Python installation in a non standard location, but it picks up a Python library from system libraries. Provide more details on how your are installing mod_wsgi and where the Python is you are using.

Comment: Graham, thank you for your response. I was able to follow your link and reinstall and get it to work. I will add an UPDATE to my above post to include exactly what I did to get it to work. Cheers and thank you once again for your contribution of mod-wsgi to the Python world!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Graham's link below I was able to get it working. I believe I had libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 installed via apt-get install on the system. I had also tried installing mod-wsgi via pip while Python virtual environment was active, but neither worked. I checked the mod-wsgi.so and mod-wsgi.so-python3.6 (or similarly named file indicating Python 3.6) and it looked like the mod-wsgi.so was symlinked to the python 3.6 .so file.

**SOLUTION:** I purged libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 from the system and followed the installation instruction guide on https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html per Graham's advice. I made sure to use ./configure --with-python=/path/to/virtualenv/python to make sure the right Python was being used to install mod-wsgi.

This solved the problem. Thank you @Graham Dumpleton.